# Check and compare the dates before planning

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I planned a training date on 10/09/2019

[image]

My problem is that when I planned a revision for example on 09/09/2019 to 11/09/2019.
I can add one recording , I would like to make one blocking... Is it possible?

[image]

Here is one idea of the code for the Controller Training. 
I don't understand, how can I compare precisely dates between Revision and Training?

Controller Training

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'


        ]);

       $date_start = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_seance'))->format('Y-m-d');
       //$date_start = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       /*
       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); */
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
       $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');


        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  /*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/
        ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
        ->first();  

        $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)/*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/
        ->first();


        $conflictFormer = Training::where('fk_former', $fk_former)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  /*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/
        ->first();  

        $conflictMotorbike = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)  
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_start)  /*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/
        ->first();  



        if(isset($conflictTraining)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate ! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictRevision)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'The motorbike is in revision! ');
        }
        if(isset($conflictRevision2)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'The motorbike is in revision! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictFormer)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate former ! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictMotorbike)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'Duplicate motorbik ! ');
        }


        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }
```

Revision Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        /*
        $date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
        $date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');*/
        $date_revision_start = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_revision_start'))->format('Y-m-d');
        $date_revision_end = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_revision_end'))->format('Y-m-d');/*
        $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
        $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');*/
        $garage = $request->get('garage');
        $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');


        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_start)/*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/

        ->first();

        $conflictTraining2 = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , $date_revision_end)/*
        ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
        ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))*/

        ->first();

        $conflict = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
        ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start)
        ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_start)
        ->first();

        $conflict2 = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_end)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_end)->first();





        if(isset($conflictTraining)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
            ->with('error', 'Le véhicule est en cours pour la date de début de la révision! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflictTraining2)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
            ->with('error', 'Le véhicule est en cours pour la date de fin de la révision! ');
        }

        if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'duplicate');
        }

       else{
        Revision::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }
```

Thank you for your help and explanation

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.  First, your `$conflictRevision` and `$conflictRevision2` queries are exactly the same.  Suggest you remove the `$conflictRevision2` as it doesn't seem to be used again in the method anyway.

As to blocking the new **Training**, your code on the Training Controller **looks correct** *to block* a conflict against a revision.  This code should stop the training from being added (create a conflict object):

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_start)
    ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_start)
    ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start'))  
    ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
    ->first();
```

A few things may be allowing the training to be recorded.

1. are you sure the $fk_motorbike is correctly entered into that query (same bike, and value is transferred from the from)?
2. is the revision entered into the database already?  IE is the form on your page actually the way you have it where a user can enter the training *first*?  If so, and the revision is getting entered after the training, then there is no revision yet created to compare against with the training query.
3. are all of the dates and hours in the correct format to compare against the database formats?  IE is the query failing because the form is sending in a different format from the DB and thus the comparison fails?  Do you need to parse anything to match?

A potentially bigger issue, however, is that while your code *to block* seems correct, the logic of this architecture *for the reverse* (don't block if the time is outside the revision) seems like it needs attention.  Because the revision may span several days, I not sure it makes sense to have the time on the revision unless it is ONLY down for revision during those times, and then available for the rest of the day.  Not sure what the point of tracking the hours of revision is, if it is a multiple day outage.

As an example, if the bike is down 10/9 - 15/9 10:00-11:00, and I want a training on 12/9 at 14:00, the query above will NOT show a conflict and WILL allow the training.  Because the bike shows it is only in revision for 1 hour every day that week.  Is that what you want?  If not, it may make more sense to remove the hours from the revision, since it is spanning multiple days.

Comment: Yes, your example is what I want to do. =-) Is it possible to validate the hours / days at the same time?

Comment: Yes :)  I think your code is correct for that example.  If it is OK to have the bike *available* during the rest of every day after the revision at 10-11, then I think your code will work.  However, did you resolve the issue from your original question - why did it allow the training?  My guess is #3, the dates weren't formatted correctly.  Any luck on this?

Comment: No, I have not solved my problem. In fact, I use the format string () for dates, it's  not correct?

Comment: No, string isn't going to format them for the database.  It depends on how your db is set up.  if those start/finish dates are DATE format, you can try: `$date_start = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_seance'))->format('Y-m-d');`  I recommend testing this with just one single line of query - check if the date matches with a known date using that parser to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I tested, I always have the same problem ... If in the page training I put on 10/09/2019 and that for revision I put on 09/09/2019 - 12/09/2019. There is no checking.... :-(

Comment: If you test **without** the two hour checks (` ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))`), does it make a conflict, or does it still allow it?

Comment: I still have the same problem. I edited my first message with my 2 models (training & revision) by removing the hours. It's weird ...

Comment: OK, that's a good sign actually.  If you are trying to make a training on the same date as a revision, without the hours query, this narrows the problem down - it is almost certainly a problem with the format of `$date_start`.  dump `$date_start` and see if it is in the same format as your database `start_date`.  If not, that format is wrong - you will have to test what works (look at the format of the database column for start_date and compare to the standard formats for Carbon/PHP)  :)

Comment: Ah, yes it's date_seance ahhaah

Comment: haha.  Good - play around with that- I'm pretty sure this will solve it for you.  Get the format correct on the dates, and it will work.

Comment: Yes... (I am really sorry for your time ....)
Thank you 10000000  times Watercaymane for your help.

Comment: Sorry to disarrangement you, could you help me solve a problem? one day when you have a few minutes, that will be my last problem i think ..Sorry again ..

Comment: Hi there, its not a problem, I'm happy to try to help.  I don't know if I can lol, but I am happy to try.  What's the issue?

Comment: it's here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982683/calculate-hours-for-training/57982811#57982811