# Calculate hours for training

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some hesitations about 3 tables which are `type_training , training & payment`.

In the table `type_training`, I have a field named `price` with 4 amounts: for example:

1 hour 00  = **100** euros

1 hour 30 = **150** euros

2 hour 00 = **200** euros

2 hour 30 = **250** euros

In my page **Training** , I encode 2 recordings for the same student.

[image]

The student `Dujardin` has booked `3 hours` for `300 euros`.

In my form `Payment`, is it possible to retrieve the amount of `300` ?

[image]

So, in my Model `Payment`? I must to calculate the difference between the `hour start` and the `hour end`?

I don't know how to do ?

Then, after having retrieved the difference of hours in my example we have `3 hours`.
How to I sum my 2 recordings in my field `Total` ? I have tried this?

```
$typetraining = Typetraining::find($request->fk_typetraining);
$data = $request->all(); 
$data['total'] = $typetraining->price + $request->????;
Payment::create($data);
```

In summary:

1) How to retrieve the difference between `hour start` & `hour end`,

2) How to calculate the amounts via the duration of my training?

For information, here is my architecture.

[image]

I thank you for your help and your explanations.

Edit: Watercamyan 19/09/2019

I adapat this?

```
createFromFormat('H:i', $request->get('hour_start'))
```

Per:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('hour_start') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="form-group-input-1">Hour start</label>
<input type="text" name="hour_start" id="hour_start" class="form-control" required="required" value="{{ old('hour_start')}}"/>
{!! $errors->first('hour_start', '<span class="help-block">:message</span>') !!}
</div>
```

Then, in my model **Training** I have like error message: Undefined variable: typeseances

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request->get('hour_start'));
$end= Carbon::parse($request->get('hour_end'));

$mins = $end->diffInMinutes($start, true);
$hoursTraining = $mins/60;

$total = $**typeTraining**->price * $hoursTraining;
```

I have like error message: Undefined variable: typeseances

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/ this should help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, as JoeGalind said, you should seriously consider re-archetecting this to be simpler.  Having to call a **TypeTraining** object that has nothing but a price, should indeed be moved up to the **Training** object.  However, let me go through a way to solve it with your existing code.

First, as you said, you need to get the number of hours of the requested training.  Unfortunately, you need part hours instead of whole hours to change the price.  If you needed whole hours, this would be easy, you could use the Carbon method `diffInHours()`.  But we can do it with `diffInMinutes()`, and then calculate out the partial hour.

First, we need to parse the hours coming in from the form into a Carbon object:

```
$start = Carbon::parse($request->get('hour_start'));
$end= Carbon::parse($request->get('hour_end'));
```

Note, I don't know how it is coming in from your form.  You might need to parse it differently if the above doesn't work.  Something like:

```
createFromFormat('H:i', $request->get('hour_start'))
```

or

```
createFromFormat('H:i:s', $request->get('hour_start'))
```

Now that you've got a carbon object, we need to calculate out the difference, including the part hours.  Again, we'll use the minutes and calculate for part hours:

```
$mins = $end->diffInMinutes($start, true);
$hoursTraining = $mins/60;
```

This will yield your multiplier (the number of hours training), something like 2.0 or 2.5 or 2.25, etc.  From here, if you have a base price for one hour (which is what I expect is in that **TypeTraining** model's `price` field), it is easy:

```
$total = $typeTraining->price * $hoursTraining;
```

The hard part, based on the way you have your code set up, is that you must pull the **TypeTraining** along with the **Training**, in order to know the price (again - just stick the price on the training to make life easier).

To get the price, something like this:

```
$training = Training::with('typeTraining')->where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student)->first();
$price = $training->typeTraining->price;
```

Now you have the price to plug into the formula above.

This is surely not exact.  And pulling the training with the FK on student is probably not what you want.  If it is generic training, or there is some other identifier, use that to pull the training to get the price.  But you can decide that later.  I can only guess at some of this, as I don't know what's coming in, or what your query needs to be, or your relationships, but this should give you an idea.  Most importantly, you were asking for how to calculate total, which is answered farther above.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your message. I edited my first message but I have an error message Undefined variable: typeTraining ???

Comment: So this is *all* in the controller to calculate the total.  The very last lines of code in my answer were an idea of how to get the price of an hour of training using your current code.  You can *then* use that price to calculate total.  Sorry - I was giving an example out of order.  So, do something **like** my last two lines, and then you can calc total with `$total = $price * $hoursTraining;`  There is a lot I don't know about your code, so this is just an example of how to get this to work.  You'll need to tweak with your own relationships and fields... but this will solve it for you :)

Comment: Excellent.  But keep in mind, this code is not going to work perfectly as cut & paste.  As you add bits of the answer, take the time to consider *how* it should work.  This will get you very close - but try to think about the 'why', and I think you'll get a lot out of it :)

Comment: Working with Carbon objects is the way to go. As Carbon is seamlessly integrated in Laravel, making macro's is a consideration as well. The exact calculation is obviously very important. Macro's will make life easier in the project. This part of the page is worth reading: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-macro

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

1. Add a "price" field to the training table. This way, if in the future, you increment that price, all your history stays with the current price.
2. After saving your "training", go ahead and calculate the hours between both dates using Carbon library, and select your current price from the TypeTraining table using this value.
3. Store the value on the Training table and then you can easily calculate the sum from anywhere.